# xamarin.forms how to show a view in the titlebar

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, xamarin.forms, master-detail

How can I put a view inside the title bar of a MasterDetailView?
I want to use xaml as much as possible.

I have a MasterDetailView which shows a Master page and a Detail page.
The Detail page then shows various content pages which change per user action.

I'd like a static title view where I can display various stats to the user.

[image]

My MasterDetailView.xaml

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"             
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"       
                  x:Class="MyApp.Views.MasterDetailView"
                  IsGestureEnabled="True"
                  MasterBehavior="Popover"
                  Title="Master Detail View">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>  
</MasterDetailPage>
```

My MasterView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.MasterView"
             Title="Master View">  
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
      <Label Text="{Binding Item1}"/>
      <Button Text="MasterView Options" Command="{Binding Option1Command}"/>
    </StackLayout >
  </ContentPage.Content>  
</ContentPage>
```

My DetailView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.DetailView"
             Title="Detail View">
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Detail View Options" Icon="options_dots.png" Order="Primary"
                 Command="{Binding OptionsCommand}" />
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>     
  <ContentPage.Content>  
  </ContentPage.Content>      
</ContentPage>
```

My TitleBarView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.TitleBarView">
  <ContentView.Content> 
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Text="{Binding Item1}"/>
      <Button Text="TitleBar Options" Command="{Binding OptionsCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

My Page1View.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.Page1View">
  <ContentView.Content> 
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
      <Label Text="{Binding Info}"/>
      <Button Text="Go To Page 2" Command="{Binding GoToPage2Command}"/>
    </StackLayout >
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

My Page2View.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.Page2View">  
  <ContentView.Content>   
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
      <Label Text="{Binding Info}"/>
      <Button Text="Go To Page 1" Command="{Binding GoToPage1Command}"/>
      <Button Text="Show Popup" Command="{Binding ShowPopupCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout >
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

I am controlling navigation throgh a navigation controller

```
public NavigationController()
{
    masterDetailView = new MasterDetailView();
    masterDetailViewModel = new MasterDetailViewModel();
    masterDetailView.BindingContext = masterDetailViewModel;

    masterView = new MasterView();
    masterViewModel = new MasterViewModel();
    masterView.BindingContext = masterViewModel;

    detailView = new DetailView();
    detailViewModel = new DetailViewModel();
    detailView.BindingContext = detailViewModel;

    titleBar = new TitleBarView();
    titleBarVM = new TitleBarViewModel();
    titleBar.BindingContext = titleBarVM;

    page1View = new Page1View();
    page1ViewModel = new Page1ViewModel();
    page1View.BindingContext = page1ViewModel;

    page2View = new Page2View();
    page2ViewModel = new Page2ViewModel();
    page2View.BindingContext = page2ViewModel;

    detailView.Content = new StackLayout()
    {
        Children = { page1View }
    };

    currentView = page1View;

    masterDetailView.Master = masterView;
    masterDetailView.MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;
    masterDetailView.Detail = new NavigationPage(detailView);
}

public void GoToPage1()
{
    if (currentView != page1View)
    {
        StackLayout sl = (StackLayout)detailView.Content;
        sl.Children.Clear();
        sl.Children.Add(page1View);
    }
}

public void GoToPage2()
{
    if (currentView != page2View)
    {
        StackLayout sl = (StackLayout)detailView.Content;
        sl.Children.Clear();
        sl.Children.Add(page2View);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't set the TitleView to of the box without extending XF and writing custom renderers, but you can set an image as page title (if the page is included in a NavigationPage using the `NavigationPage.TitleIconProperty`

```cs
var page = new Page1View();
NavigationPage.SetIconTitle(page, "foo.png");
```